# Partial fractions decomposition of rational function?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the integral $x^2/(1-x^4)$. I have the terms $A/(1-x)+B/(1+x) +(Cx+D)/(1+x^2)$. Now I have $$x^2=A(1+x)(1+x^2) +B(1-x)(1+x^2) +(Cx+D)(1-x)(1+x).$$ I put $x=1$ and I have $1^2=A(1+1)(1+1)$ so $A=1/4$. I put $x=-1$ and I have $B=1/4$ as well..is this correct now?

Comment: No, $1-x^4=(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)$. So it will be $A/(1-x)+B/(1+x)+(Cx+D)/(1+x^2)$. And this is called *partial fractions decomposition*, unrelated to integration by parts.

Comment: you might want to make your question more readable. If you take the time to write your question properly you will get better answers. For instance, put the integral sign where needed, your use of '.' and '...' is dubious, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{x^2}{1-x^{4}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \biggl(\frac{1}{1-x^{2}} - \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\biggr)$$

Answer (score 0):

The original function is not defined at x = 1 or x = -1. So you can't go with that substitution. You should try the traditional method of collecting the coefficients of x^2, x, constant terms on both sides and equating them. You should end up with 4 equations for the 4 variables - A,B, C, D.

A second method would be to use Heaviside's method.(Just google "Heaviside's method").

I must point out, that in the Heaviside's method, a substitution similar to what you've used, is done. However, we first eliminate 1/(x-a) from both sides(by multiplyting both sides by x-a), before using the substitution-   x=a.  Also, this substitution is based on a rigorous mathematical derivation( google "Heaviside's expansion theorem proof").